# Need some help aligning this text

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to align the text in my main table here.

I have a Title with three pictures and their titles next to them, which should all stay exactly where they are.

I have three other titles, Author, ISBN, and Year which I need to move to the right, and the text underneath them in the table should be centered underneath. I tried to use

```
#main table td{ 
text-align: center; 
}
```

but that centered everything, any advice? Thanks in advance.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ep483ew/9/

Here is what it should look like. [image]

Comment: Have you considered using the thead tag for table headings and tbody for the body?

Comment: Like so? #main table thead{
    text-align:right;
}

Doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `thead` and `tbody` tags so that you can keep table heading and body styles separate. In the end the HTML and CSS should look something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="#main">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main table thead tr th:nth-child(2) {/*Keep your Title Heading (2nd th) left aligned*/
    text-align: left;
}
#main table thead tr th {
    text-align: right;
}
#main table tbody tr td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT**: The picture provided suggests that the images, title, author, ISBN, and year all have their own column in the table. There is not heading text above the images and all the headings are left aligned. The reason the Title column is so large is because no cell has a declared width so it makes the columns with the widest data have a wider column. This causes the other cells to have less width and pushing them more to the right of Title. The headings are all left aligned and table cells are left aligned as well.

**EDIT 2**: Using your fiddle and instruction, the following CSS will center align the cells after the title column.

**CSS**

```
#main table thead tr th:nth-child(n+3) {/*Center th tags after the 2nd element*/
    text-align: center;
}
#main table tbody tr td:nth-child(n+3) {/*Center td tags after the 2nd element*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Did you see the picture I uploaded? Oh also, I'm not supposed to edit the HTML, it was given to us, and we are supposed to just edit the CSS

Comment: @MatthewTingle See my edit section. It describes how the table is acting.

Comment: So is there no way for me to do it with the HTML set up this way?

Comment: So the three things that need to be aligned are the title column to the left and the columns to the right of it need to be centered?

Comment: The title column doesn't need to be changed at all from the original position in my original fiddle, the other three columns need to be moved to the right and centered

Comment: @MatthewTingle I added an edit 2 section to my answer. I used your fiddle to come up with it. Try it out and I believe it is what you are looking for

Comment: The text is centered below the titles, but can they be moved to the right to where they aren't ontop of each other? This is what they look like currently http://jsfiddle.net/2ep483ew/17/embedded/result/

Comment: Yeah. use `padding-left: 1em;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're going for, but if I understand your question, then you want your headers to be aligned to the right and your content to be aligned at the center.

```
#main table th{ 
    text-align: right; 
}
 #main table td{ 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Just added them at the bottom of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ep483ew/9/) to ensure the styles don't get overridden.

Comment: I'd like Title, and the titles of the books to stay exactly where they are originally, actually here I want it to look like so http://i.imgur.com/rJCqPsa.jpg